# Xamarin.Forms How to add Backgroud Image on all pages in App

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to add one Background Image and Style it. That image must be inherited in all pages of my app. How to do it add in App.xaml in Resource Dictionary?

Comment: Does adding it as Style in App.Xaml help?

Comment: Hmmm not , i cant find a good example

Comment: Where is the image you want to set as background to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add your background image in App.xaml, you can procede this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="YourProject.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:yourProject="clr-namespace:YourProject;assembly=YourProject">
  <Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
           <FileImageSource x:Key="MyBackgroundImage">bgImage.jpg</FileImageSource>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then in your view, you reference it

```
<Image Source="{ StaticResource MyBackgroundImage}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your App.xaml add a style something like below:

```
 <Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="Page">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundImage" Value="ImageResource.png" />
 </Style>
```

For every other style, you need to add more to this.

Also if you only need this to apply on `ContentPage` it will replace the `Page` in the above style

Comment: just one more , how to style my BackgroudImage

Comment: Yes you can add those there and it should apply!