# Xamarin: How to Add a Background Image to All Pages with an AspectFill property

Tags: xamarin

Total newbie Xamarin user.

I'm trying to add a background image to all the pages in the mobile app.

This was a great resource: [Xamarin.Forms How to add Backgroud Image on all pages in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60541292/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-backgroud-image-on-all-pages-in-app)

However, I'd like to adjust the Aspect property of the image to AspectFill, so it's not so scrunched up. This is where I'm having trouble.

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.App">
...
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" >
            <Setter Property="BackgroundImageSource" Value="background_image.png" />
        </Style>
...
```

This sets the background image. How do I adjust the Aspect property for all pages? I've tried nesting an `<Image Aspect="AspectFill" />` tag within the Setter property tag, but VS gives a warning that the "property 'Value' is set more than once". Could someone help me out? I'm sure I'm making some dumb error or I've misunderstood something about Xamarin.

Thanks.

Comment: Aspect is specifically a property of the Image control, it does not apply to any other controls that I'm aware of

Comment: Have you tried - [Changing aspect ratio of background image in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925624/changing-aspect-ratio-of-background-image-in-xamarin-forms-while-keeping-content)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use the following method to set the `BackgroundImageSource` for all `ContentPage` in your app：

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" >
            <Setter Property="BackgroundImageSource" Value="background_image.png" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But we couldn't set the `AspectFill` property for it while Aspect is specifically a property of the Image control as jason said.

Of course,if you need a solution that allows you to change the AspectRatio and adjust the image you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Pages.PhotoPage">
        <Grid >
            <Image Source="background.png" Aspect="AspectFit" />
            <!-- Place here the rest of the layout for the page. -->
        </Grid >
</ContentPage>
```

Or use the solution j-petty said:

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" Source="sample.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1">
        <!--Content-->

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                <Label x:Name="KategoriePicker" Text="Was möchtest du essen?" BackgroundColor="White" />
                <Label x:Name="OrtTextBox" Text="Dein Lieferort" BackgroundColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>
        
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Hm. That's a bit disappointing. If I understand correctly, I either have to put the image in each page individually to adjust it, or have it in the resource dictionary, but unadjusted. I would have thought the code would be more flexible than that.

Comment: You can adjust your image first and then set it in the resource dictionary.